# Ruby create an array or hash with id=>company_name from a find(:all) query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, forms, hash

I have a list of vendors. I need to put them in a formtastic select menu using the collection attribute. I need the values to be id's and the label to be company names.

I have this `:as => :select, :collection => Vendor.find(:all, :order => "company_name", :select => "company_name").map(&:company_name)` but that would give me something like

```
<option value="Company A">Company A</option>
<option value="Company B">Company B</option>
```

and I need

```
<option value="1">Company A</option>
<option value="2">Company B</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map each vendor to a mini-array that contains the id and name:

```
Vendor.all(:order => "company_name", :select => "vendors.id, vendors.company_name").map{|v| [v.company_name, v.id] }
```

In this case, the "vendors" isn't strictly necessary, but if you ever combine this with other queries (eg `my_product.vendors.all(:select => ...)`) it'll get confused as to *which* id you want if you don't specify.

Comment: yes, it's reverse `[v.company_name, v.id]`. i do get the company_name but, i get blank instead of the id, it just says `<option value>`

Comment: ok, that's because of the "select" => you're only fetching the company name. I'll update appropiately.